# getMapASync - nullPointerExeption(Google maps API)

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Возращает нулевой указатель в методе getMapAsync(). Видел ответы на этот вопрос, ничего из предложенного не работает.
Код:

```
    public class CreateRoom extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
            GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
            GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
            View.OnClickListener {

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ImageButton imageButtonCancel;
        GoogleMap mMap;
        private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
        private double longitude;
        private double latitude;


        public static CreateRoom newInstance() {
            CreateRoom fragment = new CreateRoom();
            fragment.setArguments(new Bundle());
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_room, container, false);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mapToday);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            return view;
        }
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // googleMapOptions.mapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
        //    .compassEnabled(true);

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng india = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(india).title("Marker in India"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(india));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    }
```

Xml фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"

    tools:context="com.example.uncolor.ххх.CreateRoom">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Название беседы"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:background="@drawable/add_room_edit_text_style"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapToday"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Добавьте весь лог ошибки

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference.

Comment: google map в консоли разработчика активирован? в манифесте все что надо прописали?

Comment: Активирован, все прописал

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот код

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapToday);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
```

Перенесите в `onViewCreated(...)`

Вот так

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapToday);
   mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}
```